# what is the best method to loop over all odoo product and update it's record?

Tags: python, loops, odoo

i added a button to update a field in product template from another computed field 
but when i press this button only self product be update and the method didn't go over all product

i tried a lotin this problem but i can't solve it and this the simple i have added

```
@api.multi
def button_name(self):
    for template in self:
        self.name4 = self.name3

    pass
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked For me

```
@api.multi
       def button_name(self):
           for template in self.search([]):
            template.name4 = template.name3
       return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@api.multi
def button_name(self):
    for template in self.search([]):
        template.name4 = self.name3
    return True
```

Comment: your code is good to loop for all product but it's copy the self record to all product otherwise it's shouldn't be like that

Answer (score 0):

Running an SQL update would be the best choice:

```
self.env.cr.execute("UPDATE product_template SET name4 = name3;")
```